# Ethernet connection to iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I am trying to make a program that receives UDP data on a port that the user can choose. For this i am using asyncUdpSocket.

I could not find it but i believe there is a way to send data from your mac to the simulator. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can just call the simulator on the ip adress of the mac you are running on.

Sorry for bothering everybody.